# Data from Jsp not trasferred to the controller using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I've a list of items in my jsp and I want to transfer them to the controller using a bean. For some reason the list is not trasnsferred.

This is the form, using Spring tags:

```
<form:select id="MyId" path="cars" class="input-xlarge">
    <c:forEach items="${myInitialList}" var="myInitialItem">                                        
        <form:option value="${myInitialItem.id}" label="${myInitialItem.name}"></form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

This is what I have in in the bean for mapping:

```
private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>(0);

public Set<Car> getCars() {
    return this.cars;
}

public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}
```

My Car entity contain both a name and an id property.

The bean in my controller is empty. No data is transferred. I can't really figure out what's wrong. Any idea on how to rewrite this?

Update: note that I need to transfer all the list, not the selected item.

Comment: what is your controller name?

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML only the selected element in select tag its submitted when form is submitted.

In this case only one car is passed to controller when form its submitted.

For preserve all cars you need submit all elements, but are you sure? The select elements its to present list and selected one o more but no for preserve elements between request.